# Kineticjs: Image Stoke is not available when using hit region

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I use Kineticjs hit region as poposed in: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/

My Image has a stroke:

```
var lion = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: images.lion,
          x: 280,
          y: 30,
          stroke: "red" 
        });
```

The image has a stroke when did not use hit regions but when I use the following I did not see any stroke.

```
    // in order to ignore transparent pixels in an image when detecting
    // events, we first need to cache the image
    lion.cache();

    // next, we need to redraw the hit graph using the cached image
    lion.drawHitFromCache();

    // finally, we need to redraw the layer hit graph
    layer.drawHit();
```

**How can I get the stroke visible for an image when I use hit regions?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bounding box stroked you can set the drawBorder property to true:

```
lion.cache({
    drawBorder: true
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: The docu says that this is "for debugging purposes" is this really the way to go?

Comment: The docu says "cache a node and draw a red border around the bounding box"

Comment: I guess it depends on your design needs.  drawBorder is a good highlighter but if you need something more flexible you can create a group with a stroked rect with your image inside.

Comment: I am new with kineticjs. Could you please post an example?

Comment: @lavrton your example is working but is it layer.drawHit() or layer.draw()? What is the difference?

Comment: KineticJS has to canvas inside Layer object. One canvas you see on page, another one is not visiable, but used for hit detection (for any pointer events). So you can update only visiable "scene" canvas with `drawScene` function, or only hit canvas with `drawHit`, or both with just `draw`.

Comment: @lavrton Thank you! Another question where can I find these informations. The docs does not show all functions? For example you cannot find drawHit() for the Layer doc?

Comment: I think because it is not recommended to use such functions manually.